# how to change the column value based on other column value in data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change one column value based on other columns value. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
priority     comb_fld_order       start_bracs     end_bracs
1                                   (
1.1           
2.3           1                     (
2.3.1         1                                      )
3.7                                                  )
```

Expected Output:

```
priority     comb_fld_order       start_bracs     end_bracs
1                                   
1.1           
2.3           1                     (
2.3.1         1                                      )
3.7
```

Means if comb_fld_order is null then we should to remove brackets from start_bracs and end_bracs column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a boolean mask using [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html), then use  [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) to replace the values based on condition:

```
m = df['comb_fld_order'].eq('')
df['start_bracs'] = df['start_bracs'].where(~m, '')
df['end_bracs'] = df['end_bracs'].where(~m, '')
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

  priority comb_fld_order start_bracs end_bracs
0        1                                     
1      1.1                                     
2      2.3              1           (          
3    2.3.1              1                     )
4      3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method.

```
def removeBracks(record):
    if record['comb_fld_order'] is None:
       record['start_bracs'] = None
       record['end_bracs'] = None
    return record

df = df.apply(removeBracks, axis=1)
```

Comment: what is record here?

Comment: A row in your dataframe